# Bill of Materials Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, recursion

I currently have 2 tables as follows within my database:

```
Table: SampleProducts   
SampleProductsId (PK)   Name
1                             A
2                             B
3                             C
4                             D
5                             E
6                             F
7                             G

Table: SampleProductsBoms           
SampleProductsBomId (PK)    ParentId (FK)   ChildId (FK)    Quantity
1                              1             2             3
2                              2             3             4
3                              4             6             2
```

ParentId and ChildId both reference SampleProductsId

In English so I can ensure that we are all on the same page:
 Product A is made up of 3 of B
 Product B is made up of 4 of C
 Product D is made up of 2 of F

I would like to create a Stored Procedure / LinQ statement or something which I can use in my MVC 3 c# Web Application which will give me the following table structure / object to use...

Example:

```
Recursive Query to find the components of B
ProductId Name Quantity
   3        C     4
   6        F     2
```

This could go quite deep, so I really do need recursion!

Comment: No I havent. I am from a PHP background. I can do this in PHP / mySQL relatively easily. It's the Microsoft Technology that im not used to... SQL server syntax, LinQ syntax, C# syntax and now CTE syntax and learning the Visual Studio way of doing things... Whether to create a viewModel to put the query or whether it would be better / faster just to create a stored procedure... I now have headaches... If you could provide me with a simple Stored Procedure or something which will pull of that table, it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please don't add things like " - Sql Server 2008 VS2010 MVC 3 C#" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

CTE is helpfull for recursing as require in your problem statement check the link

[Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

or i think following query may also solve your purpose

```
select components.SampleProductId as productid,components.Name as Name,Quantity
from SampleProductsBOM bom
inner join SampleProducts products
on products.ParentId=bom.ParentId
inner join SampleProducts components
on components.SampleProductId=bom.ChildId
where products.Name='B'
```

Comment: Thanks, but in your link, their examples contain joins. This makes understanding what is going on extremely confusing... Im more lost than where i started.

Comment: what is confusing, you can perform your query in linq as well as you can create procedure and map that also using EF. you have to choose where you want to perform this task if your nesting is deep i think you should prefer procedure rather than linq. it will provide flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ive just taken a look at your query above... It's not recursive! I will take another look at Common table Expressions to try and make sense of it.

Comment: @Gravy my query ws not recursive but i said without recursion you can achieve this

Comment: @Amritpal No, you need recursion and writing stored procedures would be most efficient.